# Looping over files and its edition based on array information

Tags: bash, file, loops

I have a directory with a lot of files, which can be grouped based on their names. For example here I have 4 groups with 5 files in each:

```
ls - ./
# group 1
NpXynWT_apo_300K_0.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_300K_1.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_300K_2.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_300K_3.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_300K_4.pdb
# group 2
NpXynWT_apo_340K_0.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_340K_1.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_340K_2.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_340K_3.pdb
NpXynWT_apo_340K_4.pdb
# group 3
NpXynWT_com_300K_0.pdb
NpXynWT_com_300K_1.pdb
NpXynWT_com_300K_2.pdb
NpXynWT_com_300K_3.pdb
NpXynWT_com_300K_4.pdb
# group 4
NpXynWT_com_340K_0.pdb
NpXynWT_com_340K_1.pdb
NpXynWT_com_340K_2.pdb
NpXynWT_com_340K_3.pdb
NpXynWT_com_340K_4.pdb
```

So here each of the 5 files of the same group is different by the end suffix from 0 to 4:

```
NpXynWT_apo_300K_0 ... NpXynWT_apo_300K_4
NpXynWT_apo_340K_0 ... NpXynWT_apo_340K_4
etc
```

I need to loop over all of these 40 files and

1. pre-process each of the fille: adding inside of it "MODEL + A number of the file" (thus a number in range between 0 and 4) before the first string, and "ENDMDL" on the last string.
2. `cat` together the pre-processed files of the same group

In summary, as the result my script should create 4 new "combined" files, which will consist of 5 subfiles from the initial list.

For the realisation I created an array of the groups and looped it providing index from 0 to 4 as well as two loops: 1)pre-processing of each file; 2) CAT the pre-processed files together:

```
# list of 4 groups
systems=(NpXynWT_apo_300K NpXynWT_apo_340K NpXynWT_com_300K NpXynWT_com_340K)

  # pre-process files
for model in "${systems[@]}"; do  
    i="0"
    while [  $i -lt 5 ]; do
    # EDIT EXISTING FILES
    sed -i "1 i\MODEL $i" "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_"$i"_FA.pdb
    echo "ENDMDL" >> "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_"$i"_FA.pdb
    i=$[$i+1]
    done
done

# cat pre-processed filles
for model in ${systems[@]}; do
    cat "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_[0-4]_FA.pdb > "${output}/${model}.pdb"
done
```

1 - Would it be possible to merge together the both loops  ? E.g. should it be the same as

```
# pre-processing PBDs and it catting
for model in "${systems[@]}"; do  
    ##echo "$model"
    i="0"
    while [  $i -lt 5 ]; do
    k=$[$i+1]
    ## do something with pdb
    sed -i "1 i\MODEL $k" "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_"$i"_FA.pdb
    echo "ENDMDL" >> "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_"$i"_FA.pdb
    #gedit "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_"$i"_FA.pdb
    i=$[$i+1]
    done
    # now we cat together the post-processed files
    cat "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_[0-4]_FA.pdb > "${output}/${model}.pdb"
done
```

2- would it be possible simplify two operations from the first loop of the edition of the file?

```
sed -i "1 i\MODEL $i" "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_"$i"_FA.pdb
echo "ENDMDL" >> "${pdbs}"/"${model}"_"$i"_FA.pdb
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to match info from array "groups" to the files present in the folder ?

Use `find`. It is there to find files.

```
groups=(NpXynWT_apo_300K NpXynWT_apo_340K NpXynWT_com_300K NpXynWT_com_340K) 
for group in ${groups[@]}; do
    find . -name "${group}_*.pdb" -type f
done
```

You can be even more exact by using `-regex` and similar `find` options.